# Firebase Hosting 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'

Tags: reactjs, firebase, cors, firebase-hosting

When I run firebase serve to test locally, my calls to the api are working, but when I do firebase deploy and visit the url, I get the Acess-Control-Allow-Origin error for every call I make to the api.

Why can i make calls locally but fail when I use firebase hosting?

Comment: is this a google cloud function?

Comment: no just firebase hosting, I have my bundle.js and index.html in my dist folder. I firebase init choose my dist folder and say yes on SPA, then do firebase deploy. My app shows up but it can no longer make calls and recieve the data from api @Tony

Comment: What API are you referring to?

Comment: You can't call APIs on other other hosts without using CORS.  If they don't support CORS, you're going to need to build some middleware that proxies the call through your Cloud Functions.